# Text on same line

Tags: javascript, css, html

existing code which I cannot modify, here expand class is a just a functionality which on click helps user to expand collapse a function.

```
<h3 class="expand"> TREE </h3>
```

Now what I have to do is put a text(Root) with smaller font size after Tree in same line whose visibility will be controlled by javascript.

```
<h3 class="expand"> TREE <div id="root" style="display:none"><font size="2"> Root</font></div></h3>
```

Javascript functionality is working fine but Tree and Root are not coming in 1 proper line!
And yes I cannot change h3.

Comment: DIV will introduce a line break; you should use span or div with float

Comment: Phwoar... Inline styles _and_ `<font>`. I hope this is just an example.

Comment: @Jatin: A div with float will still create a line break. The "display" style of the div needs to be changed to inline or inline-block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of div use a span tag

```
<h3 class="expand"> TREE <span id="root" style="display:none"><font size="2"> Root</font></span></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to add the additional text within every matching header you could use a little jQuery to append the text based upon the css class matching?

Also, the reason your text isn't coming up on the same line is because you are using a div element. This is a block element which means it will occupy the whole horizontal width. Try using a span element or else changing the div elements style to use display:inline-block.

Here's a quick jQuery example of appending the text if it helps.

```
$('h3.expand').text($(this).append("<span style='font-size:0.9em;'>&nbps;(Root)</span>")
```

Answer (score 0):

To what are you setting the display value of root? If you use 'inline' it should work fine. Please compare:

```
<h3 class="expand"> TREE <div id="root" style="display:none;"><font size="2"> Root</font></div></h3>

<h3 class="expand"> TREE <div id="root" style="display:inline;"><font size="2"> Root</font></div></h3>
```

hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Technically a div is a block level tag so you need to define the display as inline, a span instead is an inline element (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)

Answer (score 0):

Is the generated content of the `DIV` really part of the headline? If not better add it behind for semantics:

```
<h3 class="expand">TREE</h3><div class="following_headline">ROOT</div>

<style>
.following_headline {
    position: relative;
    top: -2.5em;
    left: 0;
    float: right;
    font-size: .9em;
}
</style>
```